# QGIS Print Composer: Make grid lines around single layer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Using QGIS 2.12, I´d like to know if it´s possible to make grid lines only around a certain map layer instead of the whole worksheet?
I prefer having legends and scale bars outside the map, which makes it annoying when the grid lines and labels continue outside of the map layer.

Comment: I need a reputation of 50 to comment, so I write this as "answer". The problem is that the layer (the map I have drawn with the Add Map tool) is not regarded as an Element, so I can´t make specific grid line preferences for it. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: you can resize the map to a smaller size and then place your legend and bars OUTSIDE the map area. In this way you will have your map for example on the left side of the document and the legend on the right side of the document. Grids will only be displayed around the map area.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your layer in Composer and scroll down the **Item properties** tab until you come to **Grids**. This contains options to create grids inside the layer, borders surrounding the layer etc.

[image: Composer with grid line]